# Simple Vue Axios example from docs, but using a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is probably a very silly question, but believe me I have tried hard to figure it out, to no avail.

I have an appService.js file where I call an API like so:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://www.alphavantage.co'

const appService = {
    getPosts() {
            axios.get(`/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=xxx`)
            .then(response => this.info = response)
    }
}

export default appService
```

and then I have a Vue component (Stocks.vue) where I want to display {{ info }} like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>{{ info }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import appService from '../app.service.js'
export default {
  name: 'Stocks',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
}
</script>
```

I literally just want to dump everything I get from the API in that  tag. I will figure the rest out later.

I am basically doing the simple Axios example from the Vue docs, but using a component instead. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#Base-Example)

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're importing the appService file but you're not doing anything with it. You need to make a call to getPosts and then use the response to set the data for `{{info}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your `appService` function to *return* the promise created by `axios.get`. You also can't assign values to `this` in the function, but you can in your component.

```js
export default {
  getPosts () {
    return axios.get('/query', {
      params: { // dealing with a params object is easier IMO
        function: 'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY',
        symbol: 'MSFT',
        interval: '5min',
        apikey: 'xxx'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

then in your component, perhaps in the `created` hook

```js
data () {
  return {
    info: {} // or some other appropriate default value
  }
},
async created () {
  this.info = await appService.getPosts()
}
```